# Getting unavailable feature android.hardware.sdcard; failing! error when sdcard is present in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest, feature-detection

I am getting the following error when I am trying to install my app on my HTC device.

> Package com.org.activities requires unavailable feature
>   android.hardware.sdcard; failing!

However, I do have my SD card in my device.

Here is the code I have written in my manifest file:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sdcard" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true"/>
```

What's wrong with it? I need to check for these features as I am using  an SD card and the camera for my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hardware feature does not seem to exist. I can't find it in the reference?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features

How did you arrive at this feature name?

Comment: I dont know.. I mean it was there yesterday... anyways... thank you your link helped me a lot Raj